# Using an approximation to binomial about wind direction?

Tags: probability

here's the question wind direction is assumed to be uniformly distributed the wind is said to be Northerly if the wind that day lies within ${22.5}^{\circ}$ either side of north. Use a suitable approximation to compute the probability that in a given year the wind is classified at northerly on between 40 and 55 days (inclusive).

So here's where Im at, I know 3 approximations to different distributions:

- Possion to Binomial
- Exponential to Possion
- Normal to Binomial

This seams like a Normal to binomial,but i don't know the mean or standard deviation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each day is a separate (presumed independent and identically distributed) Bernoulli trial whose outcome is "northerly" or "not northerly."  The number of such days in a year is therefore binomial with, say, $n = 365$, and $p$ representing the chance of being northerly on any given day.

Then, since $n$ is reasonably large, the number of such days being in a given range (here, $40$ to $55$ inclusive), is suitably approximated by a normal approximation to the binomial, in which the mean and variance of the normal approximation equals the mean and variance of the corresponding binomial distribution.  You would also need to employ a continuity correction to account for the entire probability mass at $40$ and $55$ days.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the wind is northerly, is
$$p = \frac{22.5+22.5}{360} = 0.125.$$
The probability we are looking at is $\mathrm{Binomial}(365,0.125)(\{40,...,55\})$.

Indeed a normal approximation is the way to go here. Poisson would be more interesting, if 0.125 would be very small. How do we find the correct Normal distribution?
We compute expected value $(\mu = 365 \cdot 0.125)$ and variance $(\sigma^2 = 365 \cdot 0.125 \cdot 0.875)$ of the Binomial distribution and use those as parameters for the Normal distribution.

We end up with:
$$\mathrm{Binomial}(365,0.125)(\{40,...,55\}) \approx \mathrm{N}(365 \cdot 0.125, 365 \cdot 0.125 \cdot 0.875)([40, 55]).$$